# Spring Cloud Microservices - Eureka Server Security

Tags: spring, security, microservices, netflix-eureka, discovery

Since Eureka uses http/https protocols to interact with its registrants (clients), you could easily trick the eureka server by pretending to be one of its clients posting false/erroneous data to it telling that a service is down which eventually result in removal of those services from registry. This is a very likely scenario in a large system with many users.
What are the alternative security/authentication schemes to prevent such attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your service discovery is accessible from the outside, you need to add some security to it, and HTTPS will only protect from man-in-the-middle attacks, so it is not enought.

If you use Eureka with the spring cloud starter (@EnableEurekaServer), you could use spring security to protect your server.

For a simple exemple you could add :

```
security:
  user:
    name: admin
    password: password
```

And declare eureka like this on the spring-boot client side :

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://admin:password@localhost:8002/eureka
```

You can also use oauth, and all the others security protocol that spring offers.